# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck in login-loop on Kernel 5.4.0-77-generic

Tags: kernel, kubuntu

On Kernel version 5.4.0.77-generic, when I log in, it goes after a short blackscreen just straight back to the graphical login over and over again.
On Kernel 5.10.0-051000-generic, it boots without problems.

How can I figure out the issue?

Both on KDE Plasma and Ubuntu